# Where does the server side of programs run?

Tags: java, networking

If I had program and multiple clients connecting to a single server where exactly would be a good place to run the server from?

Is there a way to run the server side of the program from a website for example, since websites are servers and could always run the program? Running a server from a home computer doesn't sound like an option that most people would choose because of obvious reasons. For example: where would a small scale indie online game run their server side from?

Comment: Amazon AWS, Rackspace, Google App Engine, Microsoft Azure, etc.

Answer (score 1):

> If I had program and multiple clients connecting to a single server where exactly would be a good place to run the server from?

a computer?

> Is there a way to run the server side of the program from a website for example, since websites are servers and could always run the program?

a website is a kind of application run on a server, they are not servers.

> Running a server from a home computer doesn't sound like an option that most people would choose because of obvious reasons.

there is no "obvious" reasons why. Many web services started self hosted, and Internet has been built with service providers that are not in datacenters. I do host many services at home and they are accessible from Internet.

> For example: where would a small scale indie online game run their server side from?

You have many choices:

- a server on a pretty good Internet connection at your home/workplace/garage (with enough bandwidth and low latency),
- a virtual server hosted in a datacenter service's provider,
- a virtual server like AWS/EC2, Google apps, Azure...
- a dedicated server in a datacenter,
- a grape of dedicated servers and their caches etc.. with many engineers making the thing work perfectly
- ...

it all depends on the money you got!

Comment: If you host a website from your home computer, you are (probably) violating the terms of service (TOS) of your internet service provider (ISP).  It depends on the local laws.  In the United States, you would be violating the TOS of your ISP.  It's also not a good idea, as most ISPs optimize for download, not upload.

Answer (score 0):

websites are NOT servers.  Servers are servers, and host websites (among other things).  The "server" is the thing that people connect to, aka a physical machine.  This machine may or may not be the same machine as your client.

For an indie game, it depends on your connection.  Your options are to either run it yourself out of your room, which is entirely fine provided you have a good internet connection, or to RENT server space, which is some cluster somewhere that you rent access to.  These usually have external tech support for when things go wrong.

If you are testing code, run the server software on your local machine.  once you get it working, run it on a different computer on your local network.  once that works, run it on an external network.

Also, for reference, I run a web/file/computational/etc server out of my bedroom.  It keeps me warm in the winter.

Answer (score 0):

A Java web application runs inside an application container such as GlassFish or Tomcat (there are many others). This container runs on a physical server. Typically the physical server will be hosted in a server room of some kind. This can either be at the companies location or, more common for smaller companies, remotely hosted. A remotely hosted server can be a physical piece of hardware you own or more commonly now just a machine you rent, in fact most servers you'd probably rent now will be virtualized.

You can run a web server from a home computer, I've done it for many years, but it has some downsides. You typically have a fairly poor internet connection and a lot of ISP's don't like you hosting servers.

I recommend you look at renting a virtual server.